# Prove That $f(x)>f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)$ if $f''(x)>0$ For All $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Here's my question:

> Let $f$ be a function in a interval $I$, where $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$.
>
> Prove that for every $x,y \in I$
> $$f(x)>f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)$$

I'm sorry to say that but, I don't have an idea how to solve it. I tried to move all the arguments to one side and calculate the derivative of it.$$f'(x)-f'(y)-f''(y)(x-y)$$ I also know that since $f''(x)>0$, $f'$ is monotonic increasing. But nothing more.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: 'Iff' means that both statements are equivalent. The body of the question is concerned with 'if' alone, though. Do you know Taylors theorem with remainder?

Comment: @Thomas you are right, I changed the title. Regarding Taylors theorem, no, it's in my next course.

Comment: Use mean value theorem and the fact that $f'$ is increasing.

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368122/how-to-prove-that-a-function-is-above-a-its-tangent-line-using-the-mean-value-th/1368209#1368209) helps, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use The Mean Value theorem for the function $f$ on the interval $[x,y]$. As you know $f'$ is increasing.This implies the inequality.

Yegan

Answer (score 1):

We fix $y\in I$, and let $h:x\mapsto f(x)-f(y)-f'(y)(x-y)$. Then 
$h'(x)=f'(x)-f'(y)$, then $h'\geq 0$ in $[y,+\infty[\cap I$ ($h$ increasing) and $h'\leq 0$ in $]-\infty,y]\cap I$ ($h$ decreasing), hence $h(x)\geq h(y)=0$ for all $x\in I$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the mean value theorem, and (say $y < x$) there exists a point $c\in[y,x]$, for which
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}.$$
Thus, if $f'(t)$ is monotonously increasing, $f'(y)<f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$, as $y<c$.

Comment: Thank you. But what happens if $x<y?$ It should be right for every $x,y$, not for a particular $x>y$.

Answer (score 0):

With the helpful advice I had from the members here, I have managed to solve the question (I hope) with the following steps:

> Let $c\in(x,y)$ and $f''(x)>0 \space\forall x$

From the Mean Value Theorem we know that: $$f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$
Now we write the inequality as the following: $$-f'(y)(x-y)>f(y)-f(x)$$

$$\Rightarrow (y-x)f'(y)>f(y)-f(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow f'(y)>\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{(y-x)}$$

Since $f'$ is monotonic increasing, $$y>c\Rightarrow f'(y)>f'(c)$$

Using the mean value theorem, we get:

$$f'(y)>f'(c)$$